# Simplify Selecting 2nd list based on a previous list in C#

Tags: c#, optimization

I have 2 checked list boxes, where you select the main idea in the first one, and select a narrower focus in the 2nd box. After much work, I finally made it work, but it still seems horribly inefficient. Is there a way to optimize this?

```
List<int>  k= new List<int>();
int f = 0;
for(int j = 0; j < SubRaces.Items.Count; j++) {
    if(SubRaces.GetItemCheckState(j) == CheckState.Checked) {
        f = j;
    }               
}
for(int i = 0; i < DNDSubRace.allSubRaces.Count; i++){
    if(DNDSubRace.allSubRaces[i].MainRace.Name == Races.SelectedItem) {
        k.Add(i);
    }
}   
DNDSubRace.allSubRaces [k [f]].DNDSubRaceDescription();
SubRaceBenefits.Text = DNDSubRace.allSubRaces [k [f]].Details;
```

Comment: Is mainrace.name unique?

Comment: Yes, mainrace.name is predefined, the user is only changing the selected item, or Races.SelectedItem.

Comment: The real problem with questions like this is that the person which writes it thinks we are in his/her mind. We are not! How could I have understand anything in your code besides the first 2 lines.Your problem might be very easy to be solved but you are not helping at all.

Comment: I am sorry. I have been teaching myself and thought most of the information was not important. This is only a section from a 777 line program I have been working on for the last couple of days, and I didn't want to overwhelm others with excess.  For the future, What all should I have added for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optimize the code a little bit, for example you can add a break statement in the first for loop (this requires you to reverse the loop to get the exact same behaviour, provided `SubRaces.GetItemCheckState()` does not need to be called for every element)

```
List<int> k = new List<int>();
int f = 0;
for(int j = SubRaces.Items.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    if(SubRaces.GetItemCheckState(j) == CheckState.Checked) {
        f = j;
        break;
    }               
}

for(int i = 0; i < DNDSubRace.allSubRaces.Count; i++){
    if(DNDSubRace.allSubRaces[i].MainRace.Name == Races.SelectedItem) {
        k.Add(i);
    }
}   
DNDSubRace.allSubRaces [k [f]].DNDSubRaceDescription();
SubRaceBenefits.Text = DNDSubRace.allSubRaces [k [f]].Details;
```

Another possibility is using Linq which will be slower, but is shorter to write. When using Linq to shorten the above solution, the result is:

```
List<int> k = DNDSubRace.allSubRaces.Where(r=>r.MainRace.Name == Races.SelectedItem).ToList();
int f = 0;
for(int j = SubRaces.Items.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    if(SubRaces.GetItemCheckState(j) == CheckState.Checked) {
        f = j;
        break;
    }               
}
DNDSubRace.allSubRaces [k [f]].DNDSubRaceDescription();
SubRaceBenefits.Text = DNDSubRace.allSubRaces [k [f]].Details;
```

The first way of optimizing the code is reducing the number of cycles the upper for loop will be run for. When there are two matching elements in SubRaces then the variable `f` will be set to the index two times and the last match will stay (in the unoptimized version). If you reverse the for loop and exit it as soon as you get a match you will end up with the same behaviour, but it will be quicker.

The second rewrite wraps the second for loop into a Linq statement, which is slower but is shorter to write. Essentially it applies a filter and then copies the matching elements over to a new List.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is really cool, and I am going to use that first idea. That second one, I have never seen before, so that is also really cool. Already thinking of new ideas for that one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your answer would be to use events. When the item in the first list gets selected you can populate the second list with only its related options.

Comment: I might have worded it wrong. I have already populated the list with a different function, but when the user selects something from the new list, I am trying to access more details about that specific thing.